# addClass() on select

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a red border on field elements on validation error. I have this css class:

```
.txsignupRed {
     border: 1px solid #ff5555;
}
```

Adding the above class to a `textfield` works fine:

```
$( "#id_of_some_textfield" ).addClass( "txsignupRed" );
```

But doing the same to a `select` does not:

```
$( "#id_of_some_selectfield" ).addClass( "txsignupRed" );
$( ".some-select-class" ).addClass( "txsignupRed" );
```

But this does for some reason:

```
$(".some-select-class").css('border', "1px solid #ff5555");
```

I would also like to reference the `select` by id, not by class. How can I make it work?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3v83zzz/

Comment: If you put the CSS in the correct part of the fiddle, and add an `id` attribute to the `input`, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/q3v83zzz/4/

Comment: you put your style in a `<script type="text/css">`.  is that just a typo?

Comment: Yeah that too. Was just trying to replicate it using jsfiddle. Obviously I did a poor job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code for textbox is incorrect. You have the `id` mentioned in the `type`. It should be like this:

```
<input id="id_of_some_textfield" type="text" />
```

[Readup on `<input>` on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Also, for the CSS, use `<style>` instead of `<script>` as mentioned by @JqueryKing.

Please find the corrected and working code snippet below:

```js
$( "#id_of_some_textfield" ).addClass( "txsignupRed" );
$( "#id_of_some_select" ).addClass( "txsignupRed" );
```

```css
.txsignupRed {
    border: 1px solid #ff5555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id_of_some_textfield" type="text" />
<select id="id_of_some_select" class="some-select-class">
    <option>asdf</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:** [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3v83zzz/8/)

Comment: Is a `teextbox` a really wide `textbox`? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You got me there :D

Comment: That was a typo. My bad. Works in the fiddle now. Does not solve my problem though. I'll let the front-end developer deal with it next week. Thanks.

Comment: @dan-klasson What did I miss? I might be able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

you use style inside style tag not the script

replace

```
<script type="text/css">

.txsignupRed {
    border: 1px solid #ff5555;
}

</script>
```

use

```
<style type="text/css">

.txsignupRed {
    border: 1px solid #ff5555;
}

</style>
```